# Looping through excel rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel sheet with many rows and i need to filter rows based on cell values.

Run stops at this line

```
Set vlRowRange = .Rows("" & vlRow - 1 & ":" & vlRow + 3 & "")
```

Full Code:

```
Private Sub Filter_Rows(myRange As String, xSheet As String)

Dim vlCell As Range
Dim vlRange As Range
Dim vlRowRange As Variant
Dim vlRow As Integer

With Sheets(xSheet)
    Set vlRange = .Range(myRange)
End With

For Each vlCell In vlRange

    vlRow = vlCell.EntireRow.Row

    With Sheets(xSheet)
        Set vlRowRange = .Rows("" & vlRow - 1 & ":" & vlRow + 3 & "")
    End With

    If vlCell.Value = Me.sub_filter_1.Value Then
        vlRowRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Else
        vlRowRange.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

Next vlCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done like this

```
Dim vlRange, vlCell, vlRowRange As Range
Dim vlSheet As Worksheet
Dim vlRow As Integer

Set vlSheet = Worksheets(Me.Name)

With vlSheet
Set vlRange = .Range("A1:A10000")
End With

For Each vlCell In vlRange
If vlCell.Value = Me.sub_filter_1.Value Then
vlRow = vlCell.EntireRow.Row
Set vlRowRange = Sheet25.Rows("" & vlRow - 1 & ":" & vlRow + 3 & "")
vlRowRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
End If
Next vlCell
```

Answer (score 0):

.Rows object of Worksheet object accepts only one integer as parameter. You are trying to pass a range to it. Try using range object.

Comment: Thank you. You mean this `Set vlRowRange = .range("" & vlRow - 1 & ":" & vlRow + 3 & "")`

Comment: Yes, this should work as long as vlRow > 1, since there is no row 0 in excel